# Merge arrays and append unique values

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have an array of json like this

```
[
    {
        "u_id": "16",
        "name": "Hacker",
        "number": "9898405566",
        "GroupName": "Hackers"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "15",
        "name": "steve jobs",
        "number": "9898005566",
        "GroupName": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "16",
        "name": "Hacker",
        "number": "9898405566",
        "GroupName": "Apple"
    }
]
```

I want to merge fields with same data and append unique fields with unique data like below,

```
[
    {
        "u_id": "16",
        "name": "Hacker",
        "number": "9898405566",
        "GroupName": "Hackers,Apple"
    },
    {
        "u_id": "15",
        "name": "steve jobs",
        "number": "9898005566",
        "GroupName": "Apple"
    },
]
```

I have gone through some methods like `array_merge` and `array_unique` but failed to achieve what i want,

any help would be appreciated, Thank You..

Comment: That's an array of json

Comment: yes @aldrin27 will it make any difference?

Comment: How about showing some code you already tried? I will json_decode that json first, then use the php array functions to merge the data.

Comment: @Jaimin of course there is difference between json arrays and php arrays! The former are javascript.

Comment: Great man... Quite good solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `foreach` like as

```
$result = [];
foreach (json_decode($json,true) as $key => $value) {
    $hash = $value['u_id'];
    if(isset($result[$hash])){
        $result[$hash]['GroupName'] .= ",{$value['GroupName']}";
    }else{
        $result[$hash] = $value;
    }
}

echo json_encode(array_values($result));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/432702)

Answer (score 0):

Using array_unique() PHP function you can do that...

```
<?php
$new_array = array_unique(json_decode($old_array,true));
```

it works for me all the time, using array_unique will also remove array keys with no value...

Comment: From the php.net documentation: `"Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays."`

Comment: That is true, but using a foreach loop it can be done...foreach($old_array AS $array){ array_push($newarray,array_unique($array));}